# How do I quickly melt bronze, without magical means?

Tags: science-based, fire

So I have this character, that has been interred in a bronze statue for a thousand or so years. I need to be able to quickly melt, or get rid of the bronze so he can be released in front of my main character in a scene. However since magic is scarce in my world, it can't involve any magical means. The coat of bronze is also thick so I doubt explosives would do the trick. I'm thankful for any opinions and advice.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Worldbuilding! I see that you've tagged this question with the [tag:magic] tag, but explicitly say that you don't want to involve magic, so it might be a good idea to retag the question

Comment: Would this 1000+ year old character happen to be immune to heat? Cause we're talking 1675 F (913 C) for the melting point of bronze. Not how I'd want you to rescue me.

Comment: Saw? Unless you want to damage that character.

Comment: Rather than the magic tag consider "science based"

Comment: The character's immortal, he feels pain. I also plan for it to happen accidentally, the hero didn't really know that he was in the statue. It can happen with or without the the heros help. Also the character has lived through some torture before, and it's one of the reasons i want it to happen quickly.

Comment: Welcome to WB! I believe there is a policy that you should wait to accept an answer until 24 hours after posting to give people on the other side of the planet a chance to post. You never know - you might like their answers better.

Comment: @Caspar888 (By extension, you are able to revoke the check mark, and you can give it back to the same post at a later time if you so wish.)

Comment: @DonielF In the future I'll keep it in mind, but since his answer really did help me and I probably won't be looking further on this topic I'll let stay there.

Comment: Termite, anyone?

Comment: thermal shock may be a good choice, heat it then cool it rapidly and the statue may shatter.  a body being more squishy will not shatter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Douse the statue in aqua regia (roughly 1 part nitric acid 3 parts hydrochloric acid).

[1 guy reported](http://goldrefiningforum.com/~goldrefi/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=789) being able to chew through 1/2 oz in 15 minutes, not impressive but wheeling a blast furnace up to a statue I feel is less practical.

Granted life is gonna suck for the guy in the statue either way.

Comment: He'll get over it, if he can stand molten brass poured over him and wait a thousand years. Thanks for the link, this helps.

Comment: I've just come up with a solution thanks man

Comment: @Caspar888 brass or bronze?

Comment: See here for more information https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/55624

Answer (score 3):

The [melting point of Bronze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bronze#Properties) is about 1,742°F (this depends on the exact mix of alloys, but let's take it as gospel and ignore the specific alloy mix).

Paper is [famously known to burn at 451°F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahrenheit_451).  Wood isn't much different... but it depends on the wood, and how much wind there is, etc.  Using hardwood (e.g., oak), a bellows, and an enclosed space, it's not unreasonable to get a fire to 1,200°F.  But that won't melt Bronze.

Coal, on the other hand... coal is where it's at.  [A bellows-fired coal furance](http://rebuildingcivilization.com/content/how-hot-can-you-get-coal-fired-forge) can hit 3,500°F.  Booyah!

But we haven't solved your problem.  We now know that with coal and a little forced air we can hit the nearly 1,800°F melting point.  But if you stand that statue in a pan and wait you'll wait a long time for the Bronze to melt.  It's not enough to have the heat... you need to get the heat to every square inch of surface area possible.

A [really cool article about building a furnace](http://www.rotblattsculpture.com/Articles/buildingabronzec.html) describes building a bronze furnace out of a 5lb propane tank.  The tank experiences 2,700°F and can melt 25lb of bronze in about 30 minutes.  When you read through the article, you see that it's applying heat almost everywhere.  Now, we're talking about a block of bronze.  The furnace uses a standard size helium tank as the inner bowl, that's 7" in diameter.  You're probably using a crucible, so we're talking an ingot that's maybe 5" in diameter.

Anyway, you'll need some kind of radiators around the statue that can hit it from all sides with heat.

Which begs the question, what's the thickness of the bronze?  At the temperatures Coal can hit, a thickness of 1/4" might take a minute.  A thickness of 1" might take 5-7 minutes.

The unfortunate problem is that the guy inside died long before the bronze began to melt.  Which suggests that it needs to be cut and removed rather than melted (or you'll need something magical to protect the occupant).

---

**EDIT**

The OP pointed out the nature of the occupant and the desire to make the release something of the moment.  But, let's get something out of the way first.

- It's going to hurt.  I wouldn't be surprised if this was one angry god coming forth from the bronze of antiquity and passing through the fires of hell itself.  I'm just sayin'.  Angry.

Since this needs to be something sudden... something accidental...  There actually is one way a furnace of this calibre can exist in the world...

**A lightning bolt lights a coal seam on fire... a coal seam that happens to be near a small cave system with a natural draft.**

The [Centralia coal seam fire](http://www.centraliapa.org/how-hot-centralia-mine-fire-temperature/) has had recorded temperatures up to 1,350°F.  Only a little wind is needed to push that beyond the melting temp of bronze.  The [Burning Mountain](https://gizmodo.com/the-worlds-oldest-underground-fire-has-been-burning-fo-1539049759) coal seam has been burning an estimated 6,000 years and is thought to have been started by lightning — and it has collapsed ground around it.

So, if some unlucky merchant who thought he'd bought the world's more rare statue happened to hit a bump on the way home and the statue fell overboard... it's heavy, after all, and it happened to collapse a sinkhole into the burning seam... said merchant would have the remarkably unique experience of watching an angry, burning god climbing out of the hole.

Comment: you need more than just radiators, furnaces work by trapping heat in a confined space allowing it to build up greater temperatures. So just the heating coil isn't enough.

Comment: The dude can regenerate,(basically an immortal god) He is by far the only magical thing in the world aside from some other minor magical effects. But there aren't really any wizards that are able to conjure up a magical fire tornado. Also the technology is fairly primitive it's not as bad as in the middle ages but there isn't any reason for furnaces of that calibre to exist in the world. Also i needs to happen accidentally. What you said about the metal being cut and removed I agree. It would be quicker and less painful. I've thought about a heavy flying object (or falling) destroying it but..

Comment: There isn't any turmoil in the scene, no buildings falling, or let's say cannonballs flying twoards the statue.

Comment: @Caspar888, try my answer's edit on for size.

Comment: I like that, there's one problem though. The statue is in a city in front of a chruch. This is really my fault, because my question is lacking in information, next time I'll try to do better. I really appreciate the effort on your part though. @JBH

Comment: :-)  It's always something!  Hah!

Comment: Paper ignites __not exactly__ at 451°F, as much as I love the book by Ray Bradbury. It's in the range 218–246°C. http://www.tcforensic.com.au/docs/article10.html#2.1.1 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahrenheit_451#Title

Answer (score 2):

**You can melt metal with electrical current.**

[image: melting metal with electrical current]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d5pGN6pqkyY

Here the King of Random demonstrates a device he made to pass a high ampere / low voltage current through pieces of metal.  Electrical resistance causes heat and the heat can melt the metal.

So:your statue in front of the church.  A power line falls on it and for whatever reason automatic failsafes do not engage.  There are no shortage (pun not intended) of videos showing what power lines falling on things do to them though none of a power line melting a statue that I could find.  The current coursing through the statue heats it to melting within a few minutes.

This would be cleaner than having a colossal forge-hot fire in the neighborhood or some atomic disasters.